# How to copy path of a file in Mac OS?

Tags: macos

I am looking for a shortcut to copy the path of a file in Mac OS. I generally require it to copy paste in editor.

Comment: This should probably be moved to [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) as it's more related to everyday use of macOS than programming.

Answer (score 11):

All you need to do to copy any items path name directly to the clipboard from anywhere in the file system:

1. Navigate to the file or folder you wish to copy the path for Right-click (or Control+Click, or a Two-Finger click on trackpads) on the file or folder in the Mac Finder
2. While in the right-click menu, hold down the OPTION key to reveal the “Copy (item name) as Pathname” option, it replaces the standard Copy option
   Once selected, the file or folders path is now in the clipboard, ready to be pasted anywhere
3. The copied pathname is always the complete path, it’s not relative.

More details on the following link: http://osxdaily.com/2015/11/05/copy-file-path-name-text-mac-os-x-finder/

Comment: Amazing, saved me so much typing!

Answer (score 6):

Try with shortcut `command+option+C`:

<kbd>Cmd-Opt-C</kbd>